# Deleting the whole Linked List

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, nodes

I'm not able to understand how just by deleting a particular node current every time we are actually deleting the whole list from the memory. Here they created current and put its value as the link list but no change was done on the actual link list. Only line that made sense to me was `head_ref = NULL;` 
Here is the code:

```
/* Function to delete the entire linked list */
void deleteList(Node** head_ref)  
{  
      
/* deref head_ref to get the real head */
Node* current = *head_ref;  
Node* next;  
  
while (current != NULL)  
{  
    next = current->next;  
    free(current);  
    current = next;  
}  enter code here
      
/* deref head_ref to affect the real head back  
    in the caller. */
*head_ref = NULL;  
}
```

Comment: `current` is changing in the loop as the list is iterated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each node in the list, you:

1. Save the current iteration pointer value
2. Advance the iteration pointer to the next list node.
3. Delete the node acquired in (1)

This is repeated until the iteration node lands on NULL, which means the end of the list.

Frankly, this is easier to understand if you don't leave a dangling pointer in `*head_ref` until the end of all of this, and rather use *that* for the actual iteration. Ie.

```
void deleteList(Node** head_ref)
{
    while (*head_ref) // while we've not reached the end-of-list
    {
        Node *victim = *head_ref;  // 1. remember current node.
        *head_ref = victim->next;  // 2. advance head to next node.
        free(victim);              // 3. delete node from (1)
    }
}
```

When the above is complete the list head will be NULL and all nodes previously contained will have been destroyed. At no time is there ever a dangling pointer.

Comment: I always found your use of `victim` the perfect name choice for the node to `free()`. May be worth mentioning that sending a copy of the pointer, e.g. `void deleteList(Node *head_ref)` is all that is needed -- since there is no need to update the address of the head pointer (the list is gone).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yeah, the only reason I send it by address is the unmistakable nature of the caller code. When that pointer comes back it won't be dangling on the original now-defunct head; it will be null. I can't recall where I first saw using `victim` as the name of the object about to be disintegrated, was at least 25 years ago, but it stuck with me. I use it all the bloody time in production code.